# Trying to call another app's activity

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am trying to call some acivity in system app from my app.

I can call that activity from terminal using `am start com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest/.GravityCalibrationActivity` and it starts then.

Now I try to call it from my app with this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent (".CallGravityCalibrationActivity"));
```

Part of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest.GravityCalibrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">  
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name=".CallGravityCalibrationActivity" />  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>   
        </activity>
```

On code execution app fails with this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cyanogenmod.settings.device/com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest.GravityCalibrationActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest.GravityCalibrationActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/JSR_Settings/JSR_Settings.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Where am I going wrong (except starting to program XD)?

P.S. I don't use any IDE and don't know how. I compile my app trying to improve CM firmware to my phone. So I just execute some scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest", "com.qualcomm.sensors.qsensortest.GravityCalibrationActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```